# AWS Lambda: extract id from path

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a resource in API Gateway `/{id}/contacts`, which calls my lambda method `contacts`.

In the lambda, how do I access the `{id}` from the path, or pass it in the `event` body in the api gateway?

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {...}
```

I checked the 'Use Lambda Proxy integration' but the event does not contain that data in the lambda itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working.

After checking off `Use Lambda Proxy integration` I also had to handle the HTTP response in the code, which I didn't do at first and got errors.

The path data does appear in the event object now, but the function needs to return output with HTTP data as well, like this:

```
   var response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            "x-custom-header" : "my custom header value"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(event)
    };
     callback(null, response);
```

Comment: From the title of the question, I would've thought you were looking to do something like... define `{id}/contacts` and call `998/contacts` while extracting `"998"` as a path parameter. From the looks of this answer, that's **not** what you're looking to do. I don't really understand what the code in the answer has to do with extracting path parameters. _Please elaborate_.